# Whether by means of Silverlight 4 stick objects

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I need to implement the gluing objects to each other.
If the objects intersect the borders. attach to each other.

the objects intersect the borders

[image]

the objects attached

[image]

or it must implement code ?

Comment: Do yourself a favour and get more eyeballs on your questions by including the version agnostic `silverlight` tag on your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> must implement code

Code will have to feature but how much can vary.  Personally I'd use more code in this case.

I'd conceptually separate the red rectangles from the green borders.  The red retangle represents a single item that may or may not be attached to another.  The green borders will contain a horizontally oriented `StackPanel` and represents a set of items that are attached to each other.

Initially no item is attached to any other hence the all existing in there own green border representing an attached item groups all having only one member.

When you "attach" an item to another the red rectangle representing one of the items is removed from its existing stackpanel and added to the stackpanel contain the other.  The now empty green border is removed from view.